# How to wrap a java methods response to handle nulls

Tags: scala

I have a java method that is returning null currently.

```
val maybeUser = Try(userService.getUser) match {
  case Success(u) => u
  case _ => None
}
```

Then when I access maybeUser, I am getting a null value back:

```
val user = maybeUser match {
  case Some(u) => u
  case _ => User(1, "hello")
}
```

user ends up being null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a guard to `Success` which checks for `null`:

```
val maybeUser = Try(userService.getUser) match {
  case Success(u) if u != null => u
  case _ => None
}
```

You can make this shorter by using `filter` and `getOrElse`:

```
val user = Try(userService.getUser)
            .filter(user => user != null)
            .getOrElse(User(1, "hello"))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure that your function does not throw any exception then you the use `Option` companion object to deal with nulls.

```
Option(userService.getUser)
```

Option's apply methods takes null value and converts it into None then you can go ahead pattern matching.

```
scala> Option(null)
res0: Option[Null] = None
```

If you suspect that your method invocation might thrown an exception, then do

```
Option(Try(userService.getUser).getOrElse(null))
```

and then pattern match

Answer (score 1):

And yet another way to combine Try with option ;)

```
Try(userService.getUser).toOption.flatMap(Option(_)) match {
  case Some(user) => user
  case None       => User(1, "hello")
}
```

**However**, what I find myself doing more often than not, is writing my own extractors:

```
class NotNull[+A <: AnyRef](private val underlying: A) extends AnyVal {
  def get: A = underlying
  def isEmpty: Boolean = get == null
}

object NotNull {
  def unapply[A <: AnyRef](a: A): NotNull[A] = NotNull(a)
}
```

can then be used like:

```
Try(userService.getUser) match {
  case Success(NotNull(user)) => user
  case _                      => User(1, "hello")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks suspicious, unless there is a typo: in `case Success(u) => u` you aren't returning an `Option`, but just `User` (assuming your Java method doesn't return a Scala `Option`; if it does, and *also* can return `null`, you have bigger problems with the design). So the type of `maybeUser` is likely `AnyRef` or maybe `java.lang.Serializable`, `case Some(u)` can never match and `user` will always be `User(1, "hello")`.

In case there *is* a typo and you have `case Success(u) => Some(u)`: there is no reason to match on `Try` just to match the result again on the same two cases you just handled. Just combine the matches:

```
val user = Try(userService.getUser) match {
  case Success(u) if u != null => 
    u
  case _ => 
    User(1, "hello")
}
```

unless you are going to use `maybeUser` more than once.